# Dynamically EDIT table data, PHP, AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am looking for the cleanest way I could do the following.

```
<?php
function display_data($label, $yes_no, $model) {

    $return = "<tr><th><label>".$label."</label></th><td>";

    if ($yes_no == '1') { $return .= "Yes"; } else { $return .= "No"; }

    $return .= "</td><td>";

    if (isset($model)) {
        $return .= $model;
    }

    $return .= "</td></tr>";

    return $return;

}
?>
<table>
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Yes/No</th>
            <th>Model</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <?php
        echo display_data("Ford", $car_form["available"], $car_form["avail_model"]);
        echo display_data("Honda", $car_form["available"], $car_form["avail_model"]);
        ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to be able to EDIT the body contents of the table by just clicking on any of them, with say jquery. Changing the value and once I click out of it, it saves with AJAX.

So I should be able to click into any of the Yes/No or Model rows and change them. I'm going to have a lot of data, so I am not sure how to do this in large scale. I just don't want to have to create a individual jquery function, and divs for every single piece of data I have. If anyone can think of a cleaner way, that would be awesome.

Everything I have now, is working correctly, I just have not implemented a CRUD like system into this yet.

Comment: what did you tried so far ? I mean `JavaScript`  code.

Comment: Well, I was using jquery, toggling the table body data with inputs, marking in the inputs and saving with jquery.. It worked. But it take forever to code and I have to do every single data point in the body individually. Instead of all the table at once. Any way I can do the entire table at one time?

Comment: I see, there's always a path, kindly, some more explanation about how the table will be clicked (I mean which table cells that will accept the click), some explanation about that process in general. A screenshot with some details in it will be helpful.

Comment: Ok, give me a few moments. Thanks.

Comment: take your time.